# Cannot access Nodejs/Express Server on macOS High Sierra from other computer

Tags: node.js, macos, express, server

I started an simple express server on MacOS High Sierra. `localhost:3000` and `127.0.0.1:3000` work fine. However, when I accessed the server via `http://192.168.x.x:3000` from another computer, I didn't get any response (`ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`).

I tested the server on another MacBook (MacOS Sierra) and a Windows computer, everything works fine.

So I suppose there are something wrong with MacOS High Sierra.

Any help would be welcome. Thanks in advance.

Here is the `code` :

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))
```

Comment: enable sharing in settings

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar  Thank you for the comment. Sorry, I still don't know what to do. Can you give me more details ?

Comment: @bambam Sorry, but that one doesn't work in my case.

Comment: You should specify **what** doesn't work.

Comment: I changed the code as follow `app.listen(3000, '192.168.100.xxx', () => console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!'))`, where `192.168.100.xx` is my IP from router. However the app is still unaccessible from other computers in the network.

Comment: What's your setting in Settings -> Security -> Firewall? Open port 3000 there then

Comment: @bambam The firewall is being turned off. I use Portsscan and it seems like port 3000 is already open.

Comment: hm. I can't repro the issue on my mac w high sierra, firewall turned off too

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE MacOS**

I have tried to reinstall node, npm, change share settings, but they don't work, neither.

Finally, I updated MacOS (`10.13.4` --> `10.13.5`) and now other computers can access my server like a charm.

----------Update -------------

After a few (happy) day, the issue raised again.

Fortunately , now I pretty sure that ESET EndPoint Security was the problem since it's the last application I installed. 
So I open the ESET firewall and create a new rule which allow local network address to connect via TCP&UDP. 
The server once again works like charm.

Hope this help the other.

Answer (score -3):

Refer to https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/

> Once you have installed Node, let's try building our first web server. Create a file named "app.js", and paste the following code:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World\n');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

> After that, run your web server using node app.js, visit http://localhost:3000, and you will see a message 'Hello World'

Comment: const hostname should hold the ip assigned from the router (usually something like 192.168.1.XXX), rather than localhost to access the app from other computers in the network...